# IDW possible to fill out buffer area?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, 3d, inverse-distance-weighted

I've got a lot of points with Z-values, where I would like to construct their extent using IDW (or similar). I would like to see their extent inside my buffer, is this possible or is the tool not designed to move beyond/behind the last/first point? See picture for explanation, I can use the buffer to cut the one in shown when running the algorithm, but can't get the extent quite right.

The points are spaced approx 10 m from each other, the buffer is 50 meters from centerline.

I've got access to 3d analyst, spatial analyst and arcgis advanced desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised I can use the enviroment part, and set processing extent to the buffer line, thereby getting the correct extent. Now I just have to tweak my parameters until it is correct.